Parameters in PowerShell function contains incorrect input
I created a function Validate that accepts 2 parameters: $player and $win_set.
I debug the script at Line 17, step into the function and notice:
$player parameter contains 2 objects:

all objects in $p
all the arrays in $winning_set

$win_set is null.
I supposed I put the $p and $winning_set in the correct position of Validate function. Anyone can advise why $win_set is null?


Parameters are passed space separated in PowerShell. Remove the parentheses and the comma

To expand @SantiagoSquarzon's comment and also repeat info in the linked duplicate, your brackets are defining an array as the first parameter, rather than specifying a list of parameters - your sample is equivalent to Validate -player @($p, $winning_set) -win_set $null
